# Как поставить breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, css

Как запретить уменьшение сайта после определенной ширины, тоесть допустим меньше 300px сайт больше не уменьшался, а на устройствах с шириной меньше 300px, сайт отображался как при 300px.

Comment: `min-width`- для этого существует... Хотя все зависит от верстки и конкретной задачи... покажи верстку

Answer (score 1):

min-width: 300px; для блока с контентом